# Remove Bibliography Title

Tags: memoir, chapters

My document class is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib]{memoir}.
```

And my bibliography page is appearing like

[image]

I do not want the Bibliography heading. Instead I need References heading on the right side like in style abbrv:

[image]

I tried the solutions in some other posts but they don't work.

Comment: So you have tried `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight in-line LateX code using backticks `\`<latex code>\`` or you can indent by four spaces. It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @Werner Yes but it doesn't make it boldface or on the right side as I have shown in the image below .

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Hi Mr Johannes_B I started using latex a week ago. I could replace the text Bilblio to references but I couldnt make it left aligned. Although i know how t make it left aligned.

Comment: Looing at both other questions you posted today, your template is doing everything it can to get the chapter titles just like that. If you don't want chapter titles like that, why using the template?

Comment: @Johannes_B I started using the template at overleaf.com Bristol University Template for thesis and I have to make it work somehow now. Could you say where I have to make changes to alter that ? Thanks for help.

Comment: As far as i can tell, you would have been satisfied with the veery basic `report` class and two or three packages, depending if you have letters with diacritics, plus one for the correct hyphenation. That is really all you would need at the beginning. Reading [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) would take about two days and you would learn so much, that you could answer all the questions you had so far by yourself. <- Just my advice and experience.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes got it but could you suggest where should i make changes, just any hints or directions i will look up, could you say the structure of the template ?

Comment: LaTeX is a very very simple thing, once you know the basics (taking two days). Looking at the template, i would be very intimidated as a starter. As an experienced user, i can tell that most of the code is unneded, some is even dangerous and bound to cause strange results. (LaTeX) Templates are a reason for many to cry, which really is what templates should avoid.

Comment: @Novak007 All three questin where due to settings in the template, that are not the default and been set within the template specifically. To be honest, i would start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, the document seems to be based on [University of Bristol Thesis Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-bristol-thesis-template/kzqrfvyxxcdm). The template document defines and uses its own chapter style named `daleifmodif`.

It's quite unusual to change the chapter style for the bibliography only in a complete different format (left vs. right aligned title). Nevertheless class `memoir` allows the switching of chapter styles in the mid of the document. There are many predefined chapter styles in class `memoir`. For example, the styles `article`, `tandh`, `default`, ordered by increasing font sizes, have left aligned chapter titles in roman bold font instead of small caps.

```
\chapterstyle{article}
\bibliography{...}
```